# How do i use an Array of abstract objects? Invalid abstract type error

Tags: c++, oop, abstract

I'm coding a chess game in C++, and the **Player** has an array of 16 **pieces**, which is an abstract class for each of the individual pieces(horse, pawn, king, etc..). The compiler gives me an "invalid abstract type 'Peca' for 'pecas'. What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

Player.h

```
#include "Peca.h" // Includes Piece abstract class

using std::string;

class Jogador
{
    private:
        static int numeroDeJogador; //PlayerNumber (0-1)
        string nome;
        Peca pecas[16]; //This is the array of the abstract class Pecas (Pieces), where i want to put derived objects like Horse, king..

    public:
        string getNomeJogador(); // Return the player name

};
```

Pieces.h

```
#ifndef PECA_H
#define PECA_H
#include <string>

using std::string;

class Peca {

    private:
        int cor; //0 para as brancas, 1 para as pretas
        bool emJogo;

    public:
        Peca(int cor);
        virtual string desenha() = 0;
        virtual bool checaMovimento(int linhaOrigem, int colunaOrigem, int linhaDestino, int colunaDestino) = 0;
        int getCor();
        bool estaEmJogo();
        void setForaDeJogo(bool estado);
};
#endif
```

Derived class example:

```
#include "Peca.h"

using std::string;

class Cavalo : public Peca {
    public:
        Cavalo(int cor);
        bool checaMovimento(int linhaOrigem, int colunaOrigem, int linhaDestino, int colunaDestino);
        string desenha();
};
```

Comment: *"How do i use an Array of abstract objects?" You don't. You use either pointers (preferably of the intelligent variety) or reference wrappers (and you had better know what you're doing, so opt for plan-A). And fyi, arrays have nothing to do with this. The same problem would happen if you tried to instantiate a single `Peca` as a member. It's an instance+polymorphism issue; not an array issue.

Comment: "_This is the array of the abstract class Pecas (Pieces), where i want to put derived objects like Horse, king_" - but does it make sense to always have 16 pieces per `Jogador`? Wouldn't it be nicer with a container that could keep fewer most of the time and more when needed?

Comment: "Wouldn't it be nicer with a container that could keep fewer most of the time and more when needed?" The way i thought of implementing the game is that both players have a unique array of pieces. Then, when the game has to acess it, from the index is possible to know which piece is, if its alive and its position. That's why i thought it was better to have one single array, because it would be easier to pass to other objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array requires that the objects of the array be constructable.  You can't construct a `Peca` so you can't have an array of them.

What you need is container of pointers to a `Peca`.  Pointers are always constructable, even if what they point to cant be.  In this case you can use a `std::array<std::unique_ptr<Peca>, 16> pecas` so that you have an array of managed pointers.

Comment: Wow, we don't have an appropriate  duplicate for this so far??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's probably lost due to diversion. It has nothing to do with arrays. The same problem would surface if the member were simply `Peca obj;` Arrays add noise in that they require concrete initialization of *all* slots, but the root issue is one of simply trying to instantiate an abstract base, and I'm *certain* a duplicate or two (or several dozen) exist for that.